# 2002 Toyota Corolla - What is the replacement part for the driver-side interior door handle?

Tags: toyota, part-identification, corolla, door-handle

Some part of the plastic handle broke on the driver side of my 2002 Toyota Corolla LE. I looked up replacement parts on Toyota's website, but I'm not certain about the exact part number to match the original color.

Does anyone know what the correct part number is for this door handle?

I believe it's one of these two, but I can't tell what the difference is:

https://autoparts.toyota.com/products/product/handle-sub-assy-doo-6920602050e0

https://autoparts.toyota.com/products/product/handle-sub-assy-doo-6920602060e0

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct part number is `69206-02060-E0`, I believe. I noticed that the top of the page identified that the difference between the two pages is that there are different part numbers for the front and the rear doors.

-- UPDATE --

I called a Toyota repair center and was told that the part number I mentioned previously has been discontinued and that the replacement part number is `69206-02050-B1`. Toyota's website indicates that this is for the rear door, but the inside front and rear door handles should be the same. I told the person who was helping me that the color listed for this part was listed as "charcoal" when the part that I had looked up was listed as "neutral bone", but he said that this is the part that came up for my VIN number and should match the color.

So to summarize, this is the part number that is matched for my VIN, according to Toyota, and the other part I looked up has been discontinued. I'll have to see the part in person to verify that it is the correct color.

-- UPDATE --

I picked up the part today and it's not an exact match on the color, although this might be due to the age of the plastic. It's otherwise a match. It cost about $41 after tax, and it looks like something that I can swap out myself. In the future, I will try buying the set of four for $10 off of eBay and see how that works. This will be fine for now, even if I overpaid.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like plain old gray to me.  [Here](https://www.ebay.com/itm/255680753558?hash=item3b87c2af96:g:XnAAAOSwID5i%7EE7s&amdata=enc%3AAQAIAAAA4J4iB2KMKLecsuJgHrHrMwQoqAp68n5RXOsv2ZEk%2BB9yHW3B093bNh97Lf%2Fd4Q50kQsR5qEW9f7p7IzpTpZbk%2BSqNAcQEVbuBy4M0hdhCWnOusOLH4oFY977jtvmTjtXaKV%2FBOBmHDf%2FiCsZdis6oefWUh2VwnRCMjCumZLcPwU4Nqs8bIJaXKJWjRYRwP4rlGC9QwL%2BxzPwPUptIr4JJ5HID3uvM7hjU93MXr6FiJhNS0pTKxzzFt7kI8FTUYLJvAcNzGNBGY4svgFsNQeVFPRVO3AfkdL7cpFhTjaEJ7mH%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR9iWi-yTYg) is a set of four for $9.85.